# How to keep Appendix (as is) in TOC but have heading capitalized in report

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, appendices, report

I am using `report` and I need to have chapter headings be in all caps (including the Appendix) but not in the TOC.  E.g. instead of "Appendix A", it should appear as "APPENDIX A" inside the paper and "Appendix A" in the TOC.  I seem to have fixed the regular chapters but cannot seem to figure out how to fix the Appendix.

I can just change `\appendixname` to APPENDIX, but then it will appear as all caps in the TOC (which I would prefer not be the case).  Changing the definition of `\appendix` for report class seems to have the same effect (I believe because it's basically just redefining `\@chapapp`):

```
\renewcommand{\appendix}{\par
   \setcounter{chapter}{0}%
   \setcounter{section}{0}%
   \gdef\@chapapp{APPENDIX}% modified from \appendixname
   \gdef\thechapter{\@Alph\c@chapter}}
```

I was able to fix the regular chapter issue by keeping `\chaptername` as is and hard coding CHAPTER rather than using `\@chapapp` in the following (which was part of the original template--I did not create this so I don't fully understand what all this is doing):

```
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \refstepcounter{chapter}%
        \typeout{CHAPTER\space\thechapter.} % originally used \@chapapp
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
        {\@chapapp\space {\thechapter}: {#1}}
    \else
         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%                     
    \fi
    \chaptermark{#1}%
    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
    \if@twocolumn
        \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
    \else
        \@makechapterhead{#2}%
        \@afterheading
    \fi
}
```

Honestly, I don't understand why `\uppercase` doesn't work in the following but it doesn't capitalize "Chapter" from `\@chapapp` (this was from the original template as well) and *still* appears in the style file after the above (the chapter titles have *always* appeared in CAPS, just not the "Chapter x:" prefix).

```
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{-20\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \centering  \large\bfseries 
        \uppercase{\@chapapp\space \thechapter: #1}
    \fi
    \vskip 20\p@
    }
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Basic rule: Never change the `.cls` file ;-)

Comment: The reason, why `\uppercase{\@chapapp}` does not work is that the `\@chapapp` must be expanded first, before it can be fed to `\uppercase`, i.e. `\uppercase\expandafter{\@chapapp}` would work too

Comment: One further suggestion: Perhaps a `smallcaps` approach of `APPENDIX` would be better than to use uppercase letters with the same fontsize completely, but this is a personal opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution without hardcoding or editing the `.cls` file directly:

The O.P. was right in his assumption about `\@makechapterhead`:

```
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
```

The line with `\@chapapp` does indeed print `Chapter` (or Appendix), followed by the chapter number.

To get this uppercase, it's necessary to use `\MakeUppercase{\@chapapp}`, not `\uppercase`.

Instead of editing the `report.cls` code, it's better to use `\xpatchcmd`, looking for the line `\huge\bfseries\@chapapp..` and replacing this with the relevant code using `\MakeUppercase`.

However, this should be done only after `\appendix`, so append this patch to `\appendix` using `\xapptocmd{\appendix}{...}` (see the code please)

```
\documentclass{report}


\usepackage{xpatch}


\makeatletter

\xapptocmd{\appendix}{%
\xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{%
  \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
}{%
  \huge\bfseries \MakeUppercase{\@chapapp}\space \thechapter
}{\typeout{Patching \@makechapterhead succeeded}}{\typeout{Patching failed}}% Patching ends
}{\typeout{Appending succeeded}}{\typeout{Appending failed}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}

\appendix

\chapter{Appendix 1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please note that my code does not work for `\chapter*` like - appendices.

Comment: I figured the answer should be simple...still I feel dumb now that it was that simple.

Comment: @Jared: Well, it's simple using `\MakeUppercase`, but it isn't simple if one don't want to copy code from a class to the document.

Comment: I don't doubt that this style file is poorly written (it's old for one thing) and hardly commented at all (which means it's difficult for someone not familiar with style files, like me, to make adjustments).  This was for a thesis document so the whole point of using latex was to not have to worry about formatting but then there ended up being all sorts of minor things wrong with the style file (the university provides a word template and an "unofficial" latex template).

Comment: @Jared: Believe me, using the standard document classes such as `report` or `book`, or `memoir` is the better way than to use strange templates and hacks. There are so many good and well tested packages that can adapt the look of a document